# Why has the JSON flair changed?

Tags: bug, status-declined, flair, json

My reputation tracker used to include the flair HTML to show badges etc... but that seems to have gone away. Going to [my flair json link](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/22656.json) now, I'm getting back:

```
{"id":22656,
 "gravatarHtml":{},
 "profileUrl":"https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet",
 "displayName":"Jon Skeet",
 "reputation":"274,790",
 "badgeHtml":{}}
```

Is this deliberate, and are there any plans to reinstate the previous flair?

I'm aware that everything I'm using is pre-API... should I just take the plunge and just use the proper API instead? :)

(I've tagged this as "bug" on the grounds of it *possibly* being unintentional. None of the others particularly seemed to fit other than perhaps support. Feel free to retag appropriately.)

Comment: @Jeff: I'm nitpicking but this should be `status-bydesign` not `status-declined`, since this is not a feature proposal but a bug..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the *got flair* link on a user profile to reach the **[User Flair](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/flair)** page, and then scrolling right to the bottom and you can see:

> ### What about the old, non image based flair?
>
> The earlier methods of sharing flair are deprecated and will go away eventually. Please use the simpler image flair from this point onward!

Comment: Gah - hadn't seen that. I guess that answers that, although it's frankly annoying as I really don't *want* to serve an image link as part of the rep tracker. Most users know what their own faces look like, and having all the information in a single response is handy over 3G. Will look at whether the API makes this easier...

Comment: @Jon, FYI, it looks like this probably changed back in [September](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/flair-now-even-flairier/). (On a re-read, I feel I should clarify that I mean September was the introduction of the current image version and probably the time the others were deprecated).

Comment: The JSON feed definitely changed in the last couple of days. It looks like the API gives me what I need though.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't really explicit enough (even after an edit, unfortunatly); I didn't mean that the JSON actually changed in September - it clearly didn't - mearly that it's status changed (to deprecated). ~ Hmmm, think I need a cuppa before trying to write anything else today...

Comment: Maybe this should have been announced more aggressively, I maintain a small Android-Widget-App that displays a user's flair which now longer displays avatars or badges..