# How to get a user's avatar via stackexchange api?

Tags: support, flair, api, profile-picture

Is there a way to get a user's avatar via stackexchange-api?

Unfortunately the [flair.json is no longer supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81340/155449), so I'm looking for an alternative.

Comment: Check out http://stackapps.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, /users/{id} returns an 'email_hash' which can be used to find a gravatar..